# How to compile and run jsp file without using eclipse

Tags: java, jsp

I dont have eclipse, I want to compile jsp files and servlets. How to compile and run jsp file without using eclipse.

Comment: You or eclipse will not compile JSP, a web server will and to run JSP you need a web server like Apache Tomcat.

Comment: keep the app in tomcat webapps folder,tomcat will compile it

Comment: just deploy your JSP file in a webapp server

Comment: [This may help you](http://j-integra.intrinsyc.com/support/com/doc/servlet_com/deployingservlettoTomCat.html)

Comment: if you have only JSPs, you can dump into ROOT folder of tomcat and work with them.

Comment: for servlets, a compile step must be proceeded : use ant standalone and a build.xml file to generate your war and then deploy it to tomcat.

Comment: It annoys me that these questions are down-voted, it's a perfectly valid question. Of course you need a web container to deploy the jsp's, but the question was how do you compile a JSP outside of the container or with the programmatically. The person which down-voted this either does not understand the question or they disagree with doing it because some people take offense if you deviate from a standard which they have adopted. Please upvote the question, it truly deserves more attention.

Answer (score 2):

For compiling a JSP file on command prompt, Refer:
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19146-01/821-0790/abxcc/index.html

For running you will need a Webserver.

Answer (score 0):

You could package the web application into a WAR file then deploy it to the server and then pre-compile all the JSPs. See this article on pre-compilation of JSPs. http://javapapers.com/jsp/how-to-pre-compile-jsp/. Once they are compiled you can search for the directory to which that are compiled. In Tomcat look for the Catalina directory. For other vendors you will need to check the documentation for the location of the compiled JSPs.